# Can I access an OPC server using a Modbus Master?

Tags: opc, modbus-tcp

I'm trying to access an OPC Server on a Windows Machine using a Modbus Master on Linux and was wondering if that's possible

Answer (score 0):

Not typically. You should use an OPC client.

Answer (score 0):

No. OPC and Modbus are completely different.

Tipically you see an OPC server accessing a Modbus slave. You can model an OPC server as a two-layered component. The "upper" layer talks OPC with OPC clients. The "bottom" layer talks whatever protocol you want (in this example Modbus). The server's main task is to move data through these layers.